# The family of functions $\{ F_x: Y \to Z \; : \; F_x (y) = F(x,y)\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definition

Let $X, Y, Z$ be metric spaces such that $X, Y$ are compact. Let $F: X \times Y \to Z$ be a continuous function. If $x \in X$ we defined $F_x:Y \to Z$:

$$F_x(y)=F(x,y)$$

for every $y \in Y$. I need to prove that $\mathcal{F} = \{F_x \}_{x \in X}$ is bounded and uniformly equicontinuous.

$X \times Y$ is compact then $\vert F \vert$ has a maximum value $M$ then for every $x \in X$, $F_x$ is bounded by $M$. Where I have the problem is proving that is uniformly equicontinuous and what is the difference between uniformly equicontinuous and equicontinuous?

Comment: What metric are you using on $X\times Y$?

Comment: Answer the above question appropriately, and I will answer your question.

Comment: I think there is no difference between equicontinuous and uniformly equicontinuous. Try to write down a proof and let us know where you have a problem.